# Чи нормативно вживати слово "гортанчик" в значені "планшет" ?

Tags: вживання-слів

В телепрограмі **["Лайфхак українською"](http://1tv.com.ua/video/18217)**  (9:32 хв) радять замість слова "планшет(планшетний комп'ютер)" вживати ***"гортанчик".***

> **[Планше́тний комп'ю́тер](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%27%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80)** (планшетний персональний комп'ютер або скорочена версія (частіше вживається) планшет англ. tablet РС) — клас
> ноутбуків, обладнаних планшетним пристроєм рукописного введення,
> об'єднаним з екраном.

З ВТС сучасної української мови **["планшет"](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53407/946224.html)**

> 6》 У комп'ютерній графіці – спеціальна площина з механізмом для
> позначення положень точок, що застосовується як пристрій введення
> позицій.

**[Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/planshet)**

> пропонує декілька варіантів замінини: *гортачик, гортайчик, тицялка,
> пальцьотик, гортач, гортайко, сенсорник, табличка, дощеця.*

Який із запропонованих варіантів нормативно вживати? Чи можемо вживати просто слово "планшет"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам потрібно врахувати, що Словотвір не є офіційним джерелом, там лише пропонують варіанти українських відповідників. Звичайно, вам ніхто не може заборонити вживати слово "гортанчик" (на мою думку, це досить цікавий варіант), але слід врахувати, що не кожна людина зможе зрозуміти про що йдеться.

Варніант "планшет" зараз є більш поширеним, а крім того він є в ВТС. А цей словник є рекомендований Міністерством освіти і науки України (див. [Вікіпедію](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8)).